# hide text when checkbox is unchecked using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

the checkboxes are checked by default. if unchecked they should hide the text. how do i hide or show the text in jquery?

html:

```
    <div class="check">
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Name" id="name" checked /> <label for="name">Name</label></p>  
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Reference " id="reference" checked /> <label for="reference">Reference</label></p>
    </div>

    <div id="nametxt"> Show Name TEXT </div>
    <div id="reftxt"> Show Ref TEXT </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the id of `<div id="reftxt">` to `<div id="referencetxt">` and then you can do this:

```
$('div.check input:checkbox').bind('change',function(){
    $('#'+this.id+'txt').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

The change event will fire if its clicked on or if someone uses the keyboard to check/uncheck the checkbox.

As long as the `ID`'s of the text divs are always `checkbox ID + 'txt'` and are in `div.check` then this will handle those too.  Keeps you from having to repeat yourself as you get more checkboxes.

Answer (score 6):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#name").click(function() {
            if($('#name:checked').length) {
                $("#nametxt").show();
            } else {
                $("#nametxt").hide();
            }
        });

        $("#reference").click(function() {
            if($('#reference:checked').length) {
                $("#reftxt").show();
            } else {
                $("#reftxt").hide();
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: i tried this. if i uncheck, it hides, but when i check again, it doesn't show anything. am i missing something?

Answer (score -4):

if the check box is not checked how to display a msg through the Jquery,

You must tick the site box to accept.