# jQuery hide div when checkbox checked, show on unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to hide div when user clicks on checkbox, and show it when user unchecks that checkbox.
HTML:

```
<div id="autoUpdate" class="autoUpdate">
   content
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$('#checkbox1').change(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#autoUpdate').fadeIn('slow');
        }
        else {
            $('#autoUpdate').fadeOut('slow');
        }                   
    });
</script>
```

I am having a hard time to get this working.

Comment: this question maybe help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312502/hide-text-when-checkbox-is-unchecked-using-jquery

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Make sure to use the `ready` event.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox1').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#autoUpdate').fadeIn('slow');
        else
            $('#autoUpdate').fadeOut('slow');

    });
});
```

Comment: I believe this has to be the issue, as the code works fine on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mxRCz/

Comment: I found where I had my problem. <label> tags was causing this issue. <label id="checkbox1"><input type="checkbox"  id="checkbox1" checked="checked" /></label>
Working if I remove <label> tags. Thank you!

Comment: The right way to do it wth label would be:
<label for="cbText">Blabla</label> <input type="checkbox" value="" id="cbText" />
so the checkbox has to be outside of the label tag

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!

Comment: note: make sure you are hitting the checkbox input id/class

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide</label>
<div id="block">Some text here</div>
```

css

```
#block{display:none;background:#eef;padding:10px;text-align:center;}
```

javascript / jquery

```
$('#cbxShowHide').click(function(){
this.checked?$('#block').show(1000):$('#block').hide(1000); //time for show
});
```